# Trouble sending email with ews(Exchange Web Services)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xamarin, exchangewebservices

I am simply trying to go thru microsofts example(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx#Create) where they send an email and i´m getting an error on the

```
email.send();
```

I cant understand why..
Any of you that has been thru the same? I am using Xamarin Studio and getting pretty desperate.

Heres my code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
namespace consoleprosjekt
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxxx@xxxx", "xxxx");

        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;


        service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);

        email.ToRecipients.Add("snorri.engen@gmail.com");

        email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
        email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API");

        email.Send();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please paste the exception message. I think you need to specify also the SMTP server.

Comment: "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed."

Comment: where/how do I specify SMTP?

Comment: `SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();                 oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail); `

Comment: here the full sample code: https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=16

Comment: Simone, he is using Exchange Web Services, not SmtpClient. There's no need to specify an SMTP server.

Try enabling tracing per https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx and let's see what goes over the wire.